# How to create dynamically tables in Telerik report

Tags: telerik, report

I need to create dynamically tables and its columns with data in Report in Telerik.
I am trying in the NeedDataSource event of the table that I have created.
My code to create columns is:

```
        Telerik.Reporting.HtmlTextBox textboxGroup;
        Telerik.Reporting.HtmlTextBox textBoxTable;
        this.table1.ColumnGroups.Clear();
        this.table1.Body.Columns.Clear();
        this.table1.Body.Rows.Clear();
        //  int i = 0;
        this.table1.ColumnHeadersPrintOnEveryPage = true;

        int ColCount = dt.Columns.Count;
        for (int j = 1; j <= ColCount - 1; j++)
        {


            var tableGroupColumn = new Telerik.Reporting.TableGroup();
            this.table1.ColumnGroups.Add(tableGroupColumn);
            this.table1.Body.Columns.Add(new Telerik.Reporting.TableBodyColumn(Unit.Inch(1)));

            textboxGroup = new Telerik.Reporting.HtmlTextBox();
            textboxGroup.Style.BorderColor.Default = Color.Black;
            textboxGroup.Style.BorderStyle.Default = BorderType.Solid;
            textboxGroup.Value = dt.Columns[j].ColumnName;
            textboxGroup.Size = new SizeU(Unit.Inch(1.1), Unit.Inch(0.3));
            tableGroupColumn.ReportItem = textboxGroup;

            textBoxTable = new Telerik.Reporting.HtmlTextBox();
            textBoxTable.Style.BorderColor.Default = Color.Black;
            textBoxTable.Style.BorderStyle.Default = BorderType.Solid;
            textBoxTable.Value = "=Fields." + dt.Columns[j].ColumnName;
            textBoxTable.Size = new SizeU(Unit.Inch(1.1), Unit.Inch(0.3));
            this.table1.Body.SetCellContent(0, j++, textBoxTable);
            this.table1.Items.AddRange(new ReportItemBase[] { textBoxTable, textboxGroup });


        }
```

The header of the table is showing correctly, but not the rows with the data information.
any hint? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

j must be started at 0  and this line must be corrected as following line :
this.table1.Body.SetCellContent(0, **j**, textBoxTable);